# Height of listview.builder depend on items count/context

Tags: flutter

Height of listview.builder depend on items count.I have different count of items and in all case i have different height of my listvuew.builder.Is it posible in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to have different listview with different size, Yeah! it is possible. ListView automatically create the size for you. But you shared very little information and no code, so i persume you want to have a listView on different cases, then you can do it like this:

```
return Scaffold( 
  appBar: AppBar( 
    title:Text("ListView.builder") 
  ), 
  body: ListView.builder( 
    itemCount: count, //the variable which holds the count. 
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 
      return ListTile( 
        //Your code
        ); 
    } 
    ), 
);
```

I hope it answers your question, if not try expanding your question or letting me know it in the comment. Happy coding:)

Comment: I have listview.builder in listview.builder.Internal list(vertical) should have height(if not we will have  an error Vertical viewport was given unbounded height).My internal list have different amount of items,so i need height which will depend items/content.I have not found nice solution yet.

Comment: Adding shrinkwrap=true property to the child property should fix the problem